# Handlebars If/Else Condition Outputting Wrong Value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, handlebars.js

I have function that returns a value to be used in my view only if there is a value present. I am then referencing this value in my if condition for one view, where handlebars correctly displays the string only if there is a value. However, when I use an if/else statement in a separate view, it is resulting to the else statement regardless of the value being present or not. Why am I getting the correct output for just using the If statement, but I'm getting the wrong output if I throw an else in there?

**Function (returning a string if values are present):**

```
dataDateRangeSlug: function(){
            var startDateValue = this.getDataValue('dataDateStart');
            var startDate = new Date(startDateValue); 
            var momentStartDate = moment(startDate).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

            var endDateValue = this.getDataValue('dataDateEnd');
            var endDate = new Date(endDateValue);
            var momentEndDate = moment(endDate).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

            if (startDateValue == null){
                console.log("Statement true");
            } else {
                console.log("Statement false");
                return momentStartDate + ' - ' + momentEndDate;
            }
```

**Just using the {{#if}}:**

```
{{#if dataDateRangeSlug}}
            <p class="card-date-range">Date Range: {{this.dataDateRangeSlug}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

**Output:**

If there is a null in the dataDateRangeSlug, then p tag is not present.

If there is a value in the dataDateRangeSlug, then p tag is present with value from record.

**Using the {{#if}} and {{else}}:**

```
{{#if dataDateRangeSlug}}
                    <div class="form-inline date-start">
                        <label for="data-start-range">Data Date Start:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="data-date-start" name="dataDateStart" value="{{this.dataDateStartSlug}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline date-end">
                        <label for="data-end-range">Data Date End:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="data-date-end" name="dataDateEnd" value="{{this.dataDateEndSlug}}">
                    </div>
                {{else}}
                    <div class="add-remove-date-range">
                        <a href="#" id="date-range-add-link">Add Report Date Range</a>
                        <a href="#" id="date-range-remove-link">Remove Report Date Range</a>
                    </div>
{{/if}}
```

**Output:**

Always outputs the {{else}} code, regardless if a record has a value or is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At mine side its working as expected, have created sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u5x9fj98/1/
also how are you mapping Handlebars holders/variable? can you try it as similar to above fiddle (defining `dataDateRangeSlug` under var `Data`) .

Comment: You are right, the issue wasn't with the code, but calling the object. I only called the object property without referencing the object itself, which is why I was not receiving the correct output